# Camera Preview showing black screen in few devices but working fine on others

Tags: android

I'm showing camera preview in my application it works fine on number of devices but it shows completely black screen on few devices like Samsung galaxy duos.

I calculate the preview size according to the size of surface view and use the largest area which I can to display the preview.

Comment: Not about programming ...

Comment: As far as I remember, there is an API to query the supported preview sizes. It might be that the camera simply does not support the size of the SurfaceView? Did you check for errors as well as logcat output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the list of supported preview sizes:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

As indicated in the comment, I would guess that the camera doesn't support the size of your surface view.

It's difficult to say anything else without more information.

Comment: I'm already doing that but the issue was that I'm setting my camera preview to be rotated by 90 degrees and making according changes to calculate best preview size but galaxy duos doesn't supports camera.setDisplayOrientation(). I've also tried setting rotation parameter in Camera.Parameters but this is also of no use.